# Drupal 7 : Getting the values from radio buttons form api

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-fapi

So this is my form :

```
$active = array(0 => t('Poster'), 1 => t('Postcard'), 2=>t('Post it'));

$form['radioimage']['active'] = array(
'#type' => 'radios',
'#default_value' => isset($node->active) ? $node->active : 1,
'#options' => $active,
);
```

I want to know which radio button was selected. I am trying to access the data but I don't know what its called I can't even use devel for some reason.

I tried below but they all failed

```
$form_state['values']['radioimage']['active'][0]
$form_state['values']['radioimage']['active']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal flattens the values in the `$form_state` array by default so

```
$form['radioimage']['active']
```

will actually come out in

```
$form_state['values']['active']
```

If you want to explicitly keep your naming hierarchy then you should set the [`#tree`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#tree) key on the parent element:

```
$form['radioimage'] = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#tree' => TRUE
);
```

In that case the value will be in

```
$form_state['values']['radioimage']['active']
```

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful.